# Check if a remote site is online using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

My site checks 5 different URLs using PHP's cURL to tell if they're online. The problem is that it takes too long to load the page (especially if one of the sites it's checking is down).

I hear jQuery's ajax would work well, so I tried this code:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" id="forum-blockland-us"><b>Checking...</b></div>
<script>
$.ajax({ type: "GET",
    url: "http://forum.blockland.us/",
    cache:false,
    success: function() { 
        $("#forum-blockland-us").addClass("alert-success");
        $("#forum-blockland-us").removeClass("alert-info");
        $("#forum-blockland-us").html("<b>Online</b>");
    },
    error: function() {
        $("#forum-blockland-us").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#forum-blockland-us").removeClass("alert-info");
        $("#forum-blockland-us").html("<b>Offline</b>");
    }
});
</script>
```

But it always returns the error, even when I know 100% that the sites are online.

Comment: See "Additional notes" near the bottom of the [documentation for `.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Have you consider using lower tech methods like changing an image on the page to a green online image which is located on the server, or downloading a javascript from each server which changes the page and tells you its online.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the site is remote, there are many chances you won't be able to achieve it with javascript due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

However, in php, you could make only a HEAD request so it doesn't load contents so it will be much, much faster.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: I'm trying this. However, the problem before was the page took to long to load when the website was down. If the site is down when using HEAD, will it still take a long time?

Comment: If the site is down, it will be the same as a get or post. The trick is that you have to specify a CURLOPT_TIMEOUT of at most 5 seconds, so curl doesn't take longer :). Check the link Alireza posted, described here: http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/05/php-check-if-a-url-exists-with-curl/

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT were different. I set CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 3.

Answer (score 2):

As @Edgar said, you better do it by php, and if you want to, this is how :

```
function urlExists($url=NULL)  
{  
    if($url == NULL) return false;  
    $ch = curl_init($url);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    $data = curl_exec($ch);  
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  
    curl_close($ch);  
    if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300){  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }  
}
```

[**Source**](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/05/php-check-if-a-url-exists-with-curl/)

Comment: I should have made this clear, I was using PHP before. The problem was cURL would tremendously extend the loading time of the page if the site being checked was down.